# C# WPF: ListBox item not getting highlighted after adding mouse enter and mouse leave event handlers

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, xaml

I am developing an application in C# .NET 3.5 using WPF. I have a list box in a dialog box. When mouse comes over an item in the list box, the item gets highlighted with blue background.

I want to perform certain operations when mouse comes over an item in the list box. So I added mouse enter and mouse leave event handlers for list box item as below:

XAML code:

```
<ListBox  Name="listBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="16,367,0,0" Width="181" Height="186" >
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="listBox1_ListBoxItem_MouseEnter"/>
            <EventSetter Event="MouseLeave" Handler="listBox1_ListBoxItem_MouseLeave"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

C# code:

```
private void listBox1_ListBoxItem_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem Item = sender as ListBoxItem;

    // Perform operations using Item.

    e.Handled = false;
}

private void listBox1_ListBoxItem_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem Item = sender as ListBoxItem;

    // Perform operations using Item.

    e.Handled = false;
}
```

After adding the event handlers, the list box items do not get highlighted any more when the mouse comes over the items. How do I make the highlighting work with the event handlers?

Thank you for any help which you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding the default style for the ListBoxItem, you should extend it instead using the BasedOn attribute

```
<ListBox  Name="listBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="16,367,0,0" Width="181" Height="186" > 
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle> 
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}"> 
            <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="listBox1_ListBoxItem_MouseEnter"/> 
            <EventSetter Event="MouseLeave" Handler="listBox1_ListBoxItem_MouseLeave"/> 
        </Style> 
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle> 
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Great help! Thanks a lot. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Lost default style.  You can add the color back in.  But I like the the answer from Dtex.

```
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="listBox1_ListBoxItem_MouseEnter"/>
                <EventSetter Event="MouseLeave" Handler="listBox1_ListBoxItem_MouseLeave"/>
                <Style.Resources>
                    <!-- Background of selected item when focussed -->
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                        Color="Green"/>
                    <!-- Background of selected item when not focussed -->
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}"
                        Color="LightGreen" />
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: This is very useful information. Thank you very much. I really appreciate it.